# How to fix "Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity"?

Tags: java

I am completely new to coding, as a matter of fact, it's been a week since I started to self-study coding for building an android app.

So the problem is, when I try to run the main.activity in Android Studio it says "Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

At first, I had this - "Error: Default Activity Not Found".
Not sure, but looks like I fixed that.

But now it's saying "Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."
Seems like i have troubles with colors.xml file
(...app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:9:17:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="AndroidLayouts">
        <shared>
            <config />
        </shared>
    </component>
    <component name="ChangeListManager">
        <list def
```

As far as I understood, the problem is in the closing tag, but I don't know how to get it done correctly.

One more thing, since I am completely new to coding I was trying to learn (and do the troubleshooting) by comparing my non-working project with the working ones, and the problem is the "colors.xml" file is just the same even in the working projects, meaning it has no closing tags too.

So I'm a little confused.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your complete code and xml string?

Comment: Your colors.xml is incomplete and not a valid XML, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Santosh, as i mentioned in my post, i can see that my XML is incomplete. Can you help with completeing it?